# Django with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

can someone tell me why i am getting this error when importing my models in django?

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but 
settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

i dont know what to register in my installed_apps section.
i created a new project and registered it like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'smashbook.apps.SmashbookConfig',
 ...
 ]
```

i import my models like this:

```
from models import players
```

i have a python file "mockdata.py" which i want to use to fill my postgresql database with data using sqlalchemy.

can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your setup. The error message seems to indicate that the something in the project setup is flawed.

The first thing that happens when you run the `manage.py` script is reading the settings, first the environment variable, if set, then from `appname.settings`. You should check if this is correctly configured. (You can do a simple `cat manage.py` directory containing the script.

If that does is correct but still does not work, check that the main project folder is a module (i.e., it contains an `__init__.py` file) and that it contains `settings.py`.

**Edit**

It seems that actually you want to do testing. Please have a look at how to setup tests in Django by looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/). I usually create data dumps in yaml or JSON and simply use them in my test cases by defining the `fixtures` attribute. The great thing is that Django will take care of creating the database and all the data and  of destroying it after each test run.

In your dev environment you can easily swap out the data with the `dumpdata` and `loaddata` commands of manage.py.

Comment: maybe i did not explain correctly. when i run "python manage.py runserver" it runs without problems. but i want to run my mockdata.py seperately. i was hoping i could connect to my postgres db with sqlalchemy and add data to my database. but when i run it i get the error message above.

Comment: OK, so this is a testing setup problem. I would go with the standard Django testing framework which will take care of all the database creation for you. You simply test with `manage.py test`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, no not a testing problem. i want to fill the database with initial data. but i dont want to use fixtures or json. i want to use sql alchemy to connect to my postgres database using the models i configured in django and fill these with data

Comment: How about a script with `psql` that connects and fills the database? You can run it before `runserver`. You could also simply run your file with `python mockdata.py`.

Comment: I tried running my mockdata.py file but this gives me the error i explained in my
First post. 
I managed to load data in my
Database trough a new view. When i run the server and open the link to that view the data is loaded correctly!